# cant set minimum width of dynamically created seekbar

Tags: android, width, seekbar, css

here is the code that i am using to generate my view object:

```
        // creates the seekBar
        sBGauge = new SeekBar(this);
        sBGauge.setMax(depthL - 1);
        sBGauge.setMinimumWidth(150);
        sBGauge.setId(2000 + i);
        sBGauge.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

reguardless of what i set the sBGauge.setMinimumWidth(); to it always appears to only be about 20 wide.

any thoughts?
thanks

Edit:  to give some more info I am using this seekbar in between two textViews in a tablerow.

bump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Amit Hooda your solution did not solve my problem but it did lead me down the right path to finding a solution.

What I had to do to fix this issue was to change from a dynamically created a TableRow to a LinearLayout within my TableLayout. I was then able to get my screen width and subtract out my textviews and then set my width of the seekbar with the resulting number.

```
// gets the width of the screen to set the seekbar width
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();
width = width - 170;

LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(this);
// creates the seekBar
        sBGauge = new SeekBar(this);
        sBGauge.setMax(depthL - 1);
        sBGauge.setId(2000 + i);
        sBGauge.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, 50, 1f));
        sBGauge.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: well you never posted your layout, based on what you shared i replied, glad that it lead to solution you were looking forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(150, 150);
    sBGauge.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

you can change the value 150 and 150 according to your need.

Comment: i also have textviews and buttons in the layout so i currently have:  ' tL.addView(tR, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));' will that change affect them? @amit

Comment: no i dont think so as we are setting the layout parameters of SeekBar only

Comment: when i tried this and removed my setMinimumWidth it disappeared. @Amit

Comment: are you having layout weight for your layout?